# Is there a way to split sql results by year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, pivot

I currently have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    [Manager].[Name], 
    COUNT([Project].[ProjectId]) AS TotalProjects
FROM 
    ([Project]
INNER JOIN 
    [Manager] ON [Project].[ManagerId] = [Manager].[ManagerId])
WHERE 
    [Project].[CurrentStatusId] = 5
GROUP BY 
    [Manager].[Name]
```

It currently spits out total projects by each manager. I would like to have it split the projects out by the years they were completed. So basically count the total projects for each manager for each year (2016, 2017, and so on), as well as the total projects all time. I can use the column `[Project].[CurrentStatusDt]` for the date.

Comment: hi, what is your sql plateform?

Comment: @zip, Sql Server 2019

Comment: Please give an example of the data you are working with

Comment: @MkWTF What data do you need to see?

Comment: An example of the input data (which would be a couple rows from the Project and Manager tables) with just the columns you need to work with, which from what I understood are [Manager].[Name], [Project].[ProjectId], [Project].[CurrentStatusDt]. Also an example of the output you expect. None of it needs to be real.

Answer (score 6):

Just add the project year to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses:

```
SELECT
    [Manager].[Name], 
    YEAR([Project].[CurrentStatusDt]) PojectYear,
    COUNT([Project].[ProjectId]) AS TotalProjects
FROM [Project]
INNER JOIN [Manager] ON [Project].[ManagerId] = [Manager].[ManagerId]
WHERE [Project].[CurrentStatusId] = 5
GROUP BY [Manager].[Name], YEAR([Project].[CurrentStatusDt])
```

Side note: you don't need parentheses around the joins in SQL Server (this is a MS Access limitation).

---

**EDIT**

If you want to spread the years over columns instead of rows, then one solution is to use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT
    [Manager].[Name], 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] < CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE)
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) TotalProjects2018,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] >= CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE)
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) TotalProjects2019
FROM [Project]
INNER JOIN [Manager] ON [Project].[ManagerId] = [Manager].[ManagerId]
WHERE 
    [Project].[CurrentStatusId] = 5 
    AND [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] >= CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE)
    AND [Project].[CurrentStatusDt] <  CAST('2020-01-01' AS DATE)
GROUP BY [Manager].[Name]
```

Comment: Is there a way to split it out in sql as different years? Like all 2018's in one all 2019's in another column?